# Get Dropdown Value from a Custom Customer Address Attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, labels, address-attribute, customer-address-attribute

I'm trying to get the frontend label of my custom **address** attribute and trying this:`$address->getCustomAttribute("custom_attribute")->getValue()`, gives me the value "95905" instead of the label.

How can I get the frontend label instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this two code may be help you :-

1)

```
$custom = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($address);
```

2)

```
$customer = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer();
return $customer->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($address);
```

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: Sadly they didnt work :(

Comment: showing any error ???

Comment: try this  `$custom = $customer->getResource()
                 ->getAttribute('attribute_name')
                 ->getFrontend()
                 ->getAttribute()
                 ->getFrontendLabel();`

Answer (score 0):

$address->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($address);

Comment: It didn't work :(