# Getting a customer custom attribute label not value

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-attributes, customer-attribute, frontend-label

I know I can do the following

```
    $customerId = 1;
    $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
    $code = $customer->getCustomAttribute('attribute_code')->getValue();
```

But as the attribute is a type of "select" and not "text", it gives me the ID as the value and not the actual label

Therefore how do I get the label/frontend name of the option instead of the ID

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/313996/85907

Comment: Unfortunately not as the customer repo interface return "Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::getResource()"

Answer (score 0):

You might need to load the attribute using the `AttributeRepositoryInterface::get($entityTypeCode, $attributeCode)`.

This will return an `AttributeInterface` on which you can call `getOptions()`.

This will return an `AttributeOptionInterface[]`

Each AttributeOptionInterface exposes `getLabel()` and `getValue()`.

What you are left with is a search problem.

Also as this is a custom attribute you(or who added the attribute) in a DataPatch or InstallScript, probably  already specified the options for it. From that Option class you can extract your label based on your value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the EAV config model to retrieve this information. Add the \Magento\Eav\Model\Config to your constructor and you can use the following snippet to get your value.

```php
protected $_eavConfig;

public function __construct(... \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig ...) {
...
$this->_eavConfig = $eavConfig;
...
}

public function getAttributeLabelByValue($attributeCode, $entityType, $value) {
    try {
        $entityType = $this->_eavConfig->getEntityType($entityType);
        $attribute  = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute($entityType, $attributeCode);
        $options    = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if ($option['value'] == $value) {
                return $option['label'];
            }
        }
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        return null;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Where `$value` is whatever `getCustomAttribute('attribute_code')->getValue()` returns and where `$entityType` is "customer" or "catalog_product" or any other "eav_entity_code" from the "eav_entity_type" database table